# Is there a modern edition of Diophanti Alexandrini Arithmeticorum Libri?

Tags: new-latin, mathematics

The text [*Diophanti Alexandrini Arithmeticorum Libri Sex*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_yx9VIgeaCEYC) (Latin translation and commentary on the ancient work of Diophantus) has had a considerable impact on the history of mathematics.

I was wondering if there was a modern edition of this text (I have no problem with the Greek original not being reproduced).

Comment: Note that the actual Latin title is *Arithmetica*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I implied "libri", see the edit